# How redirect page Identity based on role asp.net core 6.0 Razor Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I want when a user login, redirect a user to a specific page in asp.net core 6.0 Razor Page using Identity but when I login it opens default page, so the code does not work

Class for Role:

```cs
namespace PFS.Utility 
{
   public class SD
   { 
       public const string AdminRole = "Admin";
       public const string SellerRole = "Seller";
       public const string DeliveryRole = "Delivery";
       public const string BuyerRole = "Buyer";
   } 
}
```

I want when a user login, redirect a user to a specific page in asp.net core 6.0 Razor Page using Identity. But when I login it open default page, so the code do not work

Code in Login.cshtml.cs:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    
    returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            if (User.IsInRole("Seller"))
            {
                return Redirect("~/Areas/Sellerr/Index");
            }
            else if (User.IsInRole("Delivery"))
            {
                return Redirect("~");
            }
            else if (User.IsInRole("Buyer"))
            {
                return Redirect("~");
            }
            else if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                return Redirect("~");
            }

            else{
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            } //stop- //redirect to this page returnUrl = ("~/")
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

Comment: Use redirect to action. Also see how identity user returnurl querysting and redircts user to this querystring value after successful login.

Comment: When debugging,which row you will go to?Do you mean `return Redirect("~");` or `return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);` not work?

Comment: I mean, for example, when the seller logs in, the code does not redirect to a specific page